# Error C2059: Syntax error : 'type' Cross Compiler

Tags: c, cross-compiling

I want to export this function from a DLL: in the header file i declare the function as follows:

```
extern void* __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl Test();
```

However, when i compile the header file using the Visual Studio Cross Compiler, i get the following error:

```
error C2059: syntax error 'type'
```

I know the problem is with this line because if i remove it, everything compiles just fine. In the same header file i also included `<stdio.h>`.

Any ideas please??

Comment: Did you try `extern  __declspec(dllexport) void* __cdecl Test();` ?

Comment: Yes and it didn't work.